# Laravel, what does "before" mean in a route group?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

When declaring a group of routes in Laravel, for a example unauthenticated group write like below

```
Route::group(array("before"=>"guest"),function(){
    //routes goes here  
}
```

What's the purpose of the "before" attribute ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that context, `guest` is a [Route Filter](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters). It is used to run a filter before any of the routes in that group are executed.

Comment: such as a security check to identify whether a user has permission to access the routes in that group

Comment: Thanks mate, Thats mean its goes to filter.php and execute Route::filter('guest', function(){} stuff before execute group routes. am i correct?

Comment: Yes that's it @Ntwobike.  If the filter returns false, the Routes inside the group are note taken into consideration.